# Meteor package dependency - Added automatically or Not

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use [rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker](https://atmospherejs.com/rajit/bootstrap3-datepicker) in my project. The project page on Atmosphere list jquery as dependency of this package.

Does meteor add jquery when I run the command

```
meteor add rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker
```

or do I have to separately add jquery

```
meteor add jquery
```

Note: `.meteor/packages`  does not show jquery as one of the added packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jquery` is listed as a dependency in [`rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker` `package.js`](https://github.com/rajit/bootstrap3-datepicker/blob/master/core/package.js#L11), this is why it will be automatically added to your app without the need to explicitly add it yourself.

`.meteor/packages` is only listing your app direct dependencies, not dependencies implied by the packages you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to install `jQuery` in addition. Usually packages have their dependencies already included, so just do `meteor add [package]` and you are good to go.

`.meteor/packages` will only list dependencies specific to your app and not a package's dependency.